# Python pandas random sample by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of samples, with a `country` column. The relative number of records in each country are:

```
d1.groupby("country").size()

country
Australia       21
Cambodia        58
China          280
India          133
Indonesia      195
Malaysia       138
Myanmar         51
Philippines     49
Singapore     1268
Taiwan          47
Thailand       273
Vietnam        288
```

How do I select, say, 100 random samples from each country, if that country has > 100 samples? (if the country has <= 100 samples, do nothing). Currently, I do this for, say, Singapore:

```
names_nonsg_ls = []
names_sg_ls = []

# if the country is not SG, add it to names_nonsg_ls. 
# else, add it to names_sg_ls, which will be subsampled later.
for index, row in d0.iterrows():
    if str(row["country"]) != "Singapore":
        names_nonsg_ls.append(str(row["header"]))
    else:
        names_sg_ls.append(str(row["header"]))

# Select 100 random names from names_sg_ls
names_sg_ls = random.sample(names_sg_ls, 100)
# Form the list of names to retain
names_ls = names_nonsg_ls + names_sg_ls
# create new dataframe
d1 = d0.loc[d0["header"].isin(names_ls)]
```

But manually a new list for each country that has >100 names is just poor form, not to mention that I first have to manually pick out the countries with > 100 names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by *country*, then sample based on the group size:

```
d1.groupby("country", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.sample(100) if len(g) > 100 else g)
```

---

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d'],
    'B': list(range(9))
})

df.groupby('A', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.sample(3) if len(g) > 3 else g)
#   A   B
#2  a   2
#0  a   0
#1  a   1
#4  b   4
#5  b   5
#6  b   6
#7  c   7
#8  d   8
```